What do I need to install in VS 2022 to get it to be able to reference "Android.Runtime.Register"?
Can someone tell me what package or VS component I am missing?
I have been tasked with taking an existing Xamarin project and try performing a bug fix, but unfortunately when I try to compile it, I get the error "CS0246    The type or namespace name 'Android' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
This is in reference to the line of code: "public bool Focusable { [Android.Runtime.Register("isFocusable", "()Z", "")] get; [Android.Runtime.Register("setFocusable", "(Z)V", "GetSetFocusable_ZHandler")] set; }"
I have tried installing anything thru the VS Installer and NuGet package manager that looks like it might have the appropriate libraries or as indicated by Copilot as being necessary to no avail.
Likely I am just missing an obvious inclusion, but for the life of me I can't figure out what that is.  Hopefully in the future my company lets me update this app to a MAUI one, but for now I'm stuck trying to get this one running so I can work on it.
